# How to differentiate messages with pattern /bank/*/accounts/ vs /bank/4/accounts/a1 in splunk query?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to write a splunk query to monitor messages grouped by the API endpoints they belong to. 
I have 2 endpoints to differentiate from:

1. /**bank**/*/**accounts**/
2. /**bank**/*/**accounts**/**a1-b2-c3**

My sample messages look as follows:

```
2019-07-15 11:42:10 [INFO] method='GET' path='/bank/4/accounts/' status='200'
```

```
2019-07-15 11:44:10 [INFO] method='GET' path='/bank/4/accounts/a1-b2-c3' status='200'
```

When I use following splunk query, I get messages which belong to both endpoints.

```
index=my_index host=my_host GET /bank/*/accounts/  | rex field=_raw "path=(?<path>.*)"
```

I tried appending following command to query, but was not successful in isolating the results:

```
| rex field=_raw ".*/accounts/(?<accountid>\w+)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rex` command extracts data from events, it does not filter them.  To filter events using regular expressions, use the `regex` command.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a splunk query with  `*-*` did the work. Complete query-

```
index=my_index host=my_host GET /bank/*/accounts/*-*
```

I liked the solution by RichG, but didnt investigate the exact usage of Regex for my case as I have found the solution for my problem.